# Is there a VBA function like IsNumeric but for Text? IsText and IsEmpty not working the same when a range is involved

Tags: excel, vba

Problem: need to be able to check a range or a single cell to see if blank.

My code to replace any text with a check mark looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
' If the range (as defined in the next line) is changed to anything but a blank, replace it with a check mark.

If Not Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("C6:C60")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error GoTo ErrorOut
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(Range(Target.Address)) Then
        Range(Target.Address).Value = "P"
        Range(Target.Address).Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
Exit Sub

ErrorOut:
Debug.Print "Error"
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It works.  But, if the user selects more than one cell and deletes them the error handling takes over.  Not a problem, because it works, but there has to be a better way.

I've been successful doing this when I wanted to check for numbers by using `If IsNumeric(Range(Target.Address)) Then`.  It works correctly if a bunch of cells are deleted at once.  But `IsText` or `IsEmpty` doesn't seem to behave exactly like `IsNumeric` and deleting a bunch of cells at once generates an error.

Comment: You can loop through Target, or exit the sub if Target.Count>1.

Comment: FWIW `Range(Target.Address)` gets you the exact same `Range` object that `Target` alone does, assuming `Target` is on the activesheet (your code has a number of problems if that's not the case, due to all these unqualified `Range` member calls)

Comment: `IsEmpty` is used to evaluate whether a `Variant` is `vbEmpty`, i.e. whether its subtype is `Variant/Empty`. This will only ever be `True` for a single cell whose `.Value` contains literally *nothing* (no formula, no value, no empty string, *nothing at all*) -- in Excel terms, *that* is what a "blank" cell is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks for the tip on `Target`, very good to know.  And your explanation on `IsEmpty` is good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rIntersect As Range
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction

    Set rng = Range("C6:C60")
    Set rIntersect = Intersect(Target, rng)
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    If rIntersect Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In rIntersect
            If wf.CountA(r) = 1 Then
                r.Value = "p"
                r.Font.Name = "Wingdings 2"
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

We loop over the `Intersection` one cell at a time.  By the way, I use:

```
r.Value = "a"
r.Font.Name = "Marlett"
```

Comment: And good tip on the Marlett font.  For the Wingdings 2, it is an uppercase P that is needed.

Comment: @Donovan  Using reasonable variable names makes it easier to see the logic.